# Add the hyperlink to multiple cell using phpExcel and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpexcel

I am trying to export MySQL database to the excel table using phpExcel. I want to set the Hyperlink on the multiple cell. I had searched many solution but almost about the single cell. Could anyone help me?
Thank you very much

```
<?php $mysql_hostname = "localhost"; 
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "test";
$prefix = "";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Could not select database");
require_once './Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$query = "SELECT * FROM testing";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

//$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

 $rowCount = 2;

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1','ID');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['id']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B1','name');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['name']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1','file_path');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $row['file_path']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D1','date');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $row['date']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C'.$rowCount, $row['file_path'])->getHyperlink()->setUrl();
  $rowCount++;
}
ob_end_clean();
 header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-   officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Test_list.xls"');
 header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

 $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
 $objWriter->save('php://output');
 exit;
?>
```

Comment: Perhaps `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C'.$rowCount)->getHyperlink()->setUrl($row['file_path']);`

Comment: Why are you resetting the values in row 1 in every iteration? That's very inefficient

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you very much for your comment. It is work sucuessfully, thank you very much for your help.  Could you please suggest the efficient way?

Comment: Efficient? Set your A1-D1 cell values ___before___ the loop